# Output an image and videos stored in a folder while the path is in the database in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

Am creating a court management system whereby a person should be able to view images and videos pertaining to a certain case

I have two related tables that is case and evidence tables

RELATIONSHIPS

Evidence model code:

```
 public function getCaseRef()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cases::className(), ['ref_no' => 'case_ref']);
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['case_ref', 'saved_by', 'saved_on', 'evidence_type'], 'required'],
        [['saved_on'], 'safe'],
        [['path'], 'safe'],
        [['case_ref', 'saved_by'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['evidence_type'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['path'], 'file']
    ];
}
```

Case model code:

```
  public function getEvidences()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Evidence::className(), ['case_ref' => 'ref_no']);
}
```

Uploading works well and I save the evidence with the case reference no. The path in the evidence model is where I save the path to where the image is uploaded to.

In the action view of the cases controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{
 $evidence = new Evidence();

 return $this->render('view', [
      'model' => $this->findModel($id),
       'id'=>$id,'evidence'=>$evidence,
       ]);

}
```

**How do I put my view model so that it displays the images/videos/pdf files stored in a folder** (corresponding to an id i.e $id passed during the click **using the path stored in the database evidence table**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the folder is in the  var myFolder and the filename in the var myFilename in your model you can  easly use it your view for image and video adding the proer value to the related attribut

```
echo "<img src='". $model->myFolder . $model->myFilename . "' >";

echo " <video width='320' height='240' controls>
 <source src='" . $model->myFolder . $model->myFilename  ."'type='video/mp4'>
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> "
```

for pdf you should use a proper extension like mpdf or if you mime is correctly setted  a simple link build with the same rules

If you have plenty of evidence connected to the case evidence, this evidence will be made available in an object with many instances or in related details with many istance. To handle this situation is sufficient that you make a foreach loop on these istances (submodels or sub object)  and for each one produces the echo as suggested in the first part of the answer.

Comment: A single case  can have multiple evidences That is many to many relationship .how do I display multiple files the above ans does not display

Comment: You're setting a bad example for the newbies - html tag attributes should be encoded. What if `$models->myFolder` contains a single quote (a perfectly valid case)? Please, either `Html::encode` your attributes or (better) use `Html::tag` to output them. Thanks!